# Where Column item is equal to specific value insert new item

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, where-clause, assign

I am trying to insert a new `Column` based off values in a separate `Column`. For the `df` below I have a `Column` of days. Where the value in this `Column` is equal to `Monday`, I want to insert a `0` into a new `Column` called `Group`.

Here is my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = ({             
   'Day' : ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'],                                                                                                                                                 
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['Group'] = np.where(df['Day'] == 'Monday', 0)
print(df)
```

Error:

> ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a value for both when the day is and isn't Monday. If you take a look at [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), that's what is referred to as `x` and `y`. Right now you only provide something for the former. So let's say all non-Mondays go to group 1, then you have:

```
df['Group'] = np.where(df['Day'] == 'Monday', 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

As simple as

```
df['Group']=(df['Day'] != 'Monday').astype(int)
```